# Почему flask_jwt_extended выдаёт ошибку при импортировании?

Tags: python, json, flask, jwt, token

Я просто пытаюсь импортировать библиотеку flask_jwt_extended для создания jwt токенов.
Я пишу:

```
import flask_jwt_extended
```

Но получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\YOGA\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm2023.3\scratches\scratch_1.py", line 2, in <module>
    import flask_jwt_extended
  File "C:\Users\YOGA\PycharmProjects\PROD_second_quals\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask_jwt_extended\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .jwt_manager import JWTManager as JWTManager
  File "C:\Users\YOGA\PycharmProjects\PROD_second_quals\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask_jwt_extended\jwt_manager.py", line 6, in <module>
    import jwt
  File "C:\Users\YOGA\PycharmProjects\PROD_second_quals\.venv\lib\site-packages\jwt\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .api_jwk import PyJWK, PyJWKSet
  File "C:\Users\YOGA\PycharmProjects\PROD_second_quals\.venv\lib\site-packages\jwt\api_jwk.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .algorithms import get_default_algorithms, has_crypto, requires_cryptography
  File "C:\Users\YOGA\PycharmProjects\PROD_second_quals\.venv\lib\site-packages\jwt\algorithms.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils import (
  File "C:\Users\YOGA\PycharmProjects\PROD_second_quals\.venv\lib\site-packages\jwt\utils.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.ec import EllipticCurve
  File "C:\Users\YOGA\PycharmProjects\PROD_second_quals\.venv\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\ec.py", line 11, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat._oid import ObjectIdentifier
  File "C:\Users\YOGA\PycharmProjects\PROD_second_quals\.venv\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\_oid.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _rust: Не найдена указанная процедура.
```

Я уже устанавил rust, но ошибка не исчезла.
Что мне делать?